# Thread is blocking whole program

Tags: c++, multithreading, block

I'm trying to make a multiclient server. I have this thread:

```
void client_thread(int new_socket)
{
    int size;
    char inbuffer[BUF];

    do
    {
        cout << "Waiting for messages: " << endl;
        size = recv(new_socket, inbuffer, BUF, 0);
    } while (true);
}
```

and this main procedure:

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //waiting for clients
        cout << "Waiting for connections..." << endl;
        new_socket = accept ( create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddress, &addrlen );

        //new client connected
        if (new_socket > 0)
        {
            //start thread
            thread(client_thread, new_socket).join();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When the first client connects, the thread starts and the server is waiting for messages from him. But the server doesn't wait for new clients anymore. I don't know why. Is it because of the infinite `do-while` loop inside the thread-function? What's the point of threads if they block your whole program if they contain infinite loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main routine blocks, because it waits for the thread to finish: `join()`.

If you don't want to block, then don't `join()` your client_thread.

This exception might come from the destruction of your anonymous thread object. When you leave the scope of `if()` all objects in this scope are destroyed. From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread you can see, the destructor calls `terminate()`. To avoid it, you can call `detach()`. So instead of `thread(client_thread, new_socket).join();`, you must say `thread(client_thread, new_socket).detach();`.

Comment: If i remove the `join()` the program crashes once a client connects with following message: `terminate called without an active exception`

Comment: what library is `thread()` coming from? Is that a function that you wrote? It's hard to say why you're getting the exception otherwise. The `join()` is definitely causing the blocking, and is masks the issue that's causing your crash.

Comment: No, it's not a custom function. It's from `std::thread` (c++0x). I also considered to compile it this way: `g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -lpthread`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! `.detach()` instead of `.join()` made it. But why is the destructor even called after `thread(...)`?

Comment: Your call to `thread()` creates an anonymous object. This object will be destructed when you leave the scope at the end of `if (...) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to create a thread and keep a reference to it until you joined it. In your code, the thread object is deallocated right after being created, hence your error if don't call join immediately.

To achieve this properly, the best way is to allocate the object on the heap, using the operator `new` and store the pointer in a list somewhere. When the thread is done it may remove itself from the list (don't forget to "mutex" it), or you could have another dedicated thread do that: perhaps you could simply have your main thread join all the other threads before exiting.